# Click handler not firing for element inside of jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox for my login form, and would like to validate password/email fields with javascript. However, the click handler I have assigned to the login button is not firing for whatever reason. Note: I have no errors appearing in my js console. My click handler looks like so:

```
$("#login-button").click(function () {

    $("#email-error").html("");
    $("#password-error").html("");
    $("#email-password-error").html("");

    var regex = new RegExp("/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i");
    var count = 0;
    alert("hey")
    if ($("#user_email").val() == "") {
        $("#email-error").html("Email is required");
        count += 1;
    } else if (!(regex.test($("#user_email").val()))) {
        $("#email-error").html("Email format incorrect");
        count += 1;
    }

    if ($("#user_password").val() == "") {
        $("#password-error").html("Password is required");
        count += 1;
    }

    if ($("#user_password").val() == "" && ($("#user_email").val() == "" || !(regex.test($("#user_email").val())))) {
        $("#password-error").html("");
        $("#email-error").html("");
        $("#email-password-error").html("Invalid email/name/password combination");
        count += 1;
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        $("#login-submit").click();
    }

});
```

And the file that gets loaded into the colorbox looks like so:

```
<div class="padding txt-center">
     <h1 class="open-sans">LOG IN TO WEBSITE</h1> 
    <!--br/>
    < div class="wrap"> <a href="#" class="button txt-center bg-facebook">login with facebook</a>  <a href="#" class="button txt-center bg-twitter">login with twitter</a> 
        <br/>
        <br/> <i></i> 
        </div-->
</div>
<!--br/-->
<div class="padding sign-form txt-center">
    <!--h1 class="no-margin-bottom">Or Use Your Email</h1--> <a href="#" onclick="$.colorbox.next()" class="underline">Do not have an account?</a> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%=f orm_for(resource, :as=>resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class=>"wrap center"}) do |f| %>
        <%=f.text_field :email, :placeholder=>'Email'%>
            <div class="error-notice" id="email-error"></div>
            <%=f.password_field :password, :placeholder=>'Password'%>
                <div class="error-notice" id="password-error"></div>
                <div class="txt-right"> <a href="#" class="forgot"><i>Forgot your password?</i></a>

                </div>
                <div class="error-notice" id="email-password-error"></div>
                <div class="button" style="width:22%;cursor:pointer;background-color:#F0F0F0;" id="login-button">LOGIN</div>
                <%if @host !='localhost' %>
                    <%=f.submit 'LOGIN', :class=>'button', :onclick =>"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Retention', 'Login']);"%>
                        <%else%>
                            <%=f.submit 'LOGIN', :class=>'button', :id=>"login-submit", :style=>"display:none;"%>
                                <%end%>
                                    <%end%>
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: Try and add `return false`add the end of your function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by putting the code inside of the click handler in a function in main.js, and then adding an onClick html attribute to the login button which then calls the previously mentioned function.

Like so:

```
<span class="button" style="width:22%;cursor:pointer;background-color:#F0F0F0;" id="login-button" onClick="login_click();">LOGIN</span>
```

Though I am still curious as to why the click event would not register before. Does it have something to do with the file for the colorbox being loaded with ajax?